# Find $\sin^2x + \sin^2y + \sin^2z$, given $\tan^2x\tan^2y + \tan^2y\tan^2z + \tan^2z\tan^2x + 2\tan^2x\tan^2y\tan^2z = 1$

Tags: trigonometry

> If $$\tan^2x\tan^2y + \tan^2y\tan^2z + \tan^2z\tan^2x + 2\tan^2x\tan^2y\tan^2z = 1$$ then find 
>   $$\sin^2x + \sin^2y + \sin^2z$$

Comment: Hint: Multiply-through by $\cos^2x \cos^2y \cos^2z$ to get an equation involving only sines and cosines. Then re-write all the cosines in terms of sines, and simplify.

Answer (score 3):

Make the every term in $\sin $
$$\sin^2 x \sin^2 y (1-\sin^2 z)+\sin^2 x\sin^2 z(1-\sin^2 y)+\sin^2 z\sin^2 x(1-\sin^2 y)+2\sin^2 x\sin^2 y \sin^2 z =(1-\sin^2 x )(1-\sin^2 y)(1-\sin^2 z)$$